# Get current current object and previous one in one row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Lets say I have a table with columns:

| Name | City | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | NewYork | 2022-01-02 | 10 |
| John | NewYork | 2022-01-03 | 20 |
| Mark | NewYork | 2022-01-01 | 30 |
| Mark | NewYork | 2022-01-03 | 40 |

now main query qould be:

```
select Name, City, Date, Value from MyTable where Date = '2022-01-03'
```

So I add date to filter and get result, easy.

Now I would like to add value from last existing date for the same object, so I need to use self join:

```
select MyTbale.Name, MyTbale.City, MyTbale.Date, MyTbale.Value, B.Value as PrevValue from MyTable A
LEFT JOIN MyTbale B on A.Name = B.Name and A.City = B.City and B.Date = (select max(Date) from MyTbale where Name = A.Name and A.City = B.City and Date < A.Date)
where Date = '2022-01-03'
```

So the result would be:

| Name | City | Date | Value | PrevValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | NewYork | 2022-01-03 | 20 | 10 |
| Mark | NewYork | 2022-01-03 | 40 | 30 |

Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [city] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [date] [date] NULL,
    [value] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([name], [city], [date], [value]) VALUES (N'John', N'NewYork', CAST(N'2022-01-02' AS Date), 10)
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([name], [city], [date], [value]) VALUES (N'John', N'NewYork', CAST(N'2022-01-03' AS Date), 20)
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([name], [city], [date], [value]) VALUES (N'Mark', N'NewYork', CAST(N'2022-01-01' AS Date), 30)
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([name], [city], [date], [value]) VALUES (N'Mark', N'NewYork', CAST(N'2022-01-03' AS Date), 40)
```

```
select * from MyTable
```

| name | city | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | NewYork | 2022-01-02 | 10 |
| John | NewYork | 2022-01-03 | 20 |
| Mark | NewYork | 2022-01-01 | 30 |
| Mark | NewYork | 2022-01-03 | 40 |

```
select
m.*
,LAG(m.value) OVER (ORDER BY m.name,m.date) as 'PrevValue'
from myTable m
```

| name | city | date | value | PrevValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | NewYork | 2022-01-02 | 10 | *null* |
| John | NewYork | 2022-01-03 | 20 | 10 |
| Mark | NewYork | 2022-01-01 | 30 | 20 |
| Mark | NewYork | 2022-01-03 | 40 | 30 |

```
select * from (
select
m.*
,LAG(m.value) OVER (ORDER BY m.name,m.date) as 'PrevValue'
from myTable m
)  t where t.date='2022-01-03'
```

| name | city | date | value | PrevValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | NewYork | 2022-01-03 | 20 | 10 |
| Mark | NewYork | 2022-01-03 | 40 | 30 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ef88aUBH)

More information (sqlshack.com/sql-lag-function-overview-and-examples). If you put an index on the fields you use "order by" (name, date etc.) it will work fast.

Comment: Thanks @omerix, my table is quite big (billions of rows) so I'm worried about the perofrmance because as I understand this query first calculates LAG for each row and then performs filtering am I correct? Can it somehow be optimized?

Comment: More information. (https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-lag-function-overview-and-examples/)  If you put an index on the fields you use "order by", it will work fast. (name, date etc.)